# My popup window works in jsfiddle but not on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bpopup

I am working on a little project where I am trying to implement a popup window from a button. I am using code that I found on this developers site [bPopup](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup). I played around with the code on JSFiddle and it works but when I uploaded the code to my site it is not working. I tried playing around with the way I am referencing the jquery and bpopup javascript files and still nothing. I also looked into the DOM Ready issue and I believe I am ok there but maybe I am wrong.

When I run the site with these three files the output is a button that when I click it nothing happens and the video in the iframe shows below it (before I click the button). Thanks in advance for any help!!

Html (file name blog.html, it is linked to from my index.html):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css"/>
    <script src="bPopup.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <meta name ="viewport" content = "width=640, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>OneLine</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button that triggers the popup -->
    <button id="my-button">POP IT UP</button>
    <!-- Element to pop up -->
    <div id="element_to_pop_up">
      <a class="bClose"></a>
     <iframe width="280" height="157.5" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iw8wDinJxBQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (file name animate.css):

```
/* PopUp Window */ 
#element_to_pop_up {
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:15px;
    color:#000;
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
    min-width:300px;
    min-height: 400px;
}
.bClose{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:5px;
}
```

Javascript (file name bPopup.js):

```
    // Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
    // Encapsulation
    // $ is assigned to jQuery
    ;(function($) {

         // DOM Ready
        $(function() {

            // Binding a click event
            // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
            $('#my-button').on('click', function(e) {

                // Prevents the default action to be triggered.
                e.preventDefault();

                // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
                $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();

            });

        });

    })(jQuery);

/*********************************************************************************
 * @name: bPopup
 * @author: (c)Bjoern Klinggaard (http://dinbror.dk/bpopup - twitter@bklinggaard)
 * @version: 0.7.0.min
 *********************************************************************************/
(function(b) {
    b.fn.bPopup = function(n, p) {
        function t() {
            b.isFunction(a.onOpen) && a.onOpen.call(c);
            k = (e.data("bPopup") || 0) + 1;
            d = "__bPopup" + k;
            l = "auto" !== a.position[1];
            m = "auto" !== a.position[0];
            i = "fixed" === a.positionStyle;
            j = r(c, a.amsl);
            f = l ? a.position[1] : j[1];
            g = m ? a.position[0] : j[0];
            q = s();
            a.modal && b('<div class="bModal ' + d + '"></div>').css({
                "background-color": a.modalColor,
                height: "100%",
                left: 0,
                opacity: 0,
                position: "fixed",
                top: 0,
                width: "100%",
                "z-index": a.zIndex + k
            }).each(function() {
                a.appending && b(this).appendTo(a.appendTo)
            }).animate({
                opacity: a.opacity
            }, a.fadeSpeed);
            c.data("bPopup", a).data("id", d).css({
                left: !a.follow[0] && m || i ? g : h.scrollLeft() + g,
                position: a.positionStyle || "absolute",
                top: !a.follow[1] && l || i ? f : h.scrollTop() + f,
                "z-index": a.zIndex + k + 1
            }).each(function() {
                a.appending && b(this).appendTo(a.appendTo);
                if (null != a.loadUrl) switch (a.contentContainer = b(a.contentContainer || c), a.content) {
                case "iframe":
                    b('<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>').attr("src", a.loadUrl).appendTo(a.contentContainer);
                    break;
                default:
                    a.contentContainer.load(a.loadUrl)
                }
            }).fadeIn(a.fadeSpeed, function() {
                b.isFunction(p) && p.call(c);
                u()
            })
        }
        function o() {
            a.modal && b(".bModal." + c.data("id")).fadeOut(a.fadeSpeed, function() {
                b(this).remove()
            });
            c.stop().fadeOut(a.fadeSpeed, function() {
                null != a.loadUrl && a.contentContainer.empty()
            });
            e.data("bPopup", 0 < e.data("bPopup") - 1 ? e.data("bPopup") - 1 : null);
            a.scrollBar || b("html").css("overflow", "auto");
            b("." + a.closeClass).die("click." + d);
            b(".bModal." + d).die("click");
            h.unbind("keydown." + d);
            e.unbind("." + d);
            c.data("bPopup", null);
            b.isFunction(a.onClose) && setTimeout(function() {
                a.onClose.call(c)
            }, a.fadeSpeed);
            return !1
        }
        function u() {
            e.data("bPopup", k);
            b("." + a.closeClass).live("click." + d, o);
            a.modalClose && b(".bModal." + d).live("click", o).css("cursor", "pointer");
            (a.follow[0] || a.follow[1]) && e.bind("scroll." + d, function() {
                q && c.stop().animate({
                    left: a.follow[0] && !i ? h.scrollLeft() + g : g,
                    top: a.follow[1] && !i ? h.scrollTop() + f : f
                }, a.followSpeed)
            }).bind("resize." + d, function() {
                if (q = s()) j = r(c, a.amsl), a.follow[0] && (g = m ? g : j[0]), a.follow[1] && (f = l ? f : j[1]), c.stop().each(function() {
                    i ? b(this).css({
                        left: g,
                        top: f
                    }, a.followSpeed) : b(this).animate({
                        left: m ? g : g + h.scrollLeft(),
                        top: l ? f : f + h.scrollTop()
                    }, a.followSpeed)
                })
            });
            a.escClose && h.bind("keydown." + d, function(a) {
                27 == a.which && o()
            })
        }
        function r(a, b) {
            var c = (e.width() - a.outerWidth(!0)) / 2,
                d = (e.height() - a.outerHeight(!0)) / 2 - b;
            return [c, 20 > d ? 20 : d]
        }
        function s() {
            return e.height() > c.outerHeight(!0) + 20 && e.width() > c.outerWidth(!0) + 20
        }
        b.isFunction(n) && (p = n, n = null);
        var a = b.extend({}, b.fn.bPopup.defaults, n);
        a.scrollBar || b("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
        var c = this,
            h = b(document),
            e = b(window),
            k, d, q, l, m, i, j, f, g;
        this.close = function() {
            a = c.data("bPopup");
            o()
        };
        return this.each(function() {
            c.data("bPopup") || t()
        })
    };
    b.fn.bPopup.defaults = {
        amsl: 50,
        appending: !0,
        appendTo: "body",
        closeClass: "bClose",
        content: "ajax",
        contentContainer: null,
        escClose: !0,
        fadeSpeed: 250,
        follow: [!0, !0],
        followSpeed: 500,
        loadUrl: null,
        modal: !0,
        modalClose: !0,
        modalColor: "#000",
        onClose: null,
        onOpen: null,
        opacity: 0.7,
        position: ["auto", "auto"],
        positionStyle: "absolute",
        scrollBar: !0,
        zIndex: 9997
    }
})(jQuery);
```

All files are in the same directory on my site.

EDIT: THESE ARE THE ERRORS I GET WHEN RUNNING THE CONSOLE ERRORS

```
[18:14:51.018] GET http://www.onelineco.net/Blog.html [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 47ms]
[18:14:51.076] GET http://www.onelineco.net/animate.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 68ms]
[18:14:51.077] GET http://www.onelineco.net/bPopup.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 68ms]
[18:14:51.078] GET http://www.onelineco.net/jquery-1.8.2.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 78ms]
[18:14:51.106] ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined @ http://www.onelineco.net/bPopup.js:23
[18:14:51.201] GET http://www.onelineco.net/jquery-1.8.2.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 61ms]
[18:14:51.232] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ http://www.onelineco.net/Blog.html
[18:14:51.285] GET http://www.youtube.com/embed/iw8wDinJxBQ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 141ms]
[18:14:51.386] Unrecognized at-rule or error parsing at-rule '@-moz-viewport'. @ http://www.youtube.com/embed/iw8wDinJxBQ:14
[18:14:51.386] Unrecognized at-rule or error parsing at-rule '@viewport'. @ http://www.youtube.com/embed/iw8wDinJxBQ:17
[18:14:51.391] Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.391] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.391] Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.391] Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.391] Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.393] Expected media feature name but found '-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio'. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.393] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.393] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-topleft'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.393] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.411] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-topright'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.411] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-bottomright'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.411] Error in parsing value for 'cursor'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.413] Unknown property '-moz-background-size'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.416] Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-embed-vflkVRvOv.css:1
[18:14:51.877] Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.877] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.877] Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.877] Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.877] Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.879] Expected media feature name but found '-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio'. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.879] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.879] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-topleft'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.879] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.880] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-topright'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.880] Unknown property '-moz-border-radius-bottomright'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.880] Error in parsing value for 'cursor'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://s.ytimg.com/yts/cssbin/www-player-actions-vflaifYoV.css:1
[18:14:51.886] Use of getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. Use getAttributeNS() instead. @ resource://dwhelper/util-service.jsm:567
[18:14:51.886] Use of attributes' ownerDocument attribute is deprecated. @ resource://dwhelper/util-service.jsm:567
[18:14:51.886] Use of attributes' nodeType attribute is deprecated. It always returns 2. @ resource://dwhelper/util-service.jsm:571
[18:14:51.886] Use of attributes' firstChild attribute is deprecated. Use value instead. @ resource://dwhelper/util-service.jsm:580
```

Comment: Check the console for errors, particularly `Illegal token`

Comment: I'm using Aptana 3 and in the .js file I dont see any errors.

Comment: Check the browser's console(Press F12(if avalable))

Comment: I ran the console errors in firefox and there are a bunch of errors. thanks for letting me know about this! but I cant say I know how to fix most of them. could I copy and paste the errors in here?

Comment: Add them to the question

Comment: Posted. thanks for helping with this, highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Now fix the errors one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load jQuery before your other script that is dependant on it.

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="bPopup.js"></script>
```

Comment: ahhh, fixed it but it still doesnt work. Of all those errors, this one seems interesting, [18:29:58.118] ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined @ http://www.onelineco.net/bPopup.js:23.

Comment: this is what I have in line 23 in the bpopup.js file     })(jQuery);

Comment: @Eric_S you shouldn't have the ReferenceError any more if you place jQuery before your own script.

Comment: I had the file jquery-1.8.2.js instead of jquery-1.8.2.min.js.....fixed it and now it works. Again a million thanks for the help. Left you good feedback.